# Imprimir vocales minúscula en mayúscula

Tags: c

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de que AEIOU (mayúsculas) se pueda imprimir en  el siguiente codigo (ya que solamente me toma aeiou en minúsculas) en vez de estar escribiendo:

```
nombre[i]=='A'||nombre[i]=='E'||nombre[i]=='I'||nombre[i]=='O'||nombre[i]=='U'

    for(i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        if(nombre[i]=='a'||nombre[i]=='e'||nombre[i]=='i'||nombre[i]=='o'||nombre[i]=='u')
        {
            if(voc<2)
            {
                printf("%c",toupper(nombre[i]));
                voc=voc+1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurren varias soluciones; en tu caso, con un limitado conjunto de valores válidos, posiblemente lo más fácil de leer sea usando un `switch`:

```
for( i = 0; i < 20;  ++i ) {
  if( voc < 2 ) {
    switch( nombre [i] ) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
      printf( "%c", toupper( nombre[i] ) );
      ++voc;
      break;

    default:
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

El 'default' está, mayormente, para evitar el *aviso* cuando el compilador se pasa de *puntilloso*. En la mayoría de los casos, se puede quitar.